# android talking to .net webservice

Tags: android, .net, rest, soap

What is the best way for an android device to talk to a .net webservice? I've looked at ksoap2 but I'm not completely sold on it because it's old and doesn't seem to be getting updated anymore. I know google likes REST designs better. So I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

i would just use REST and JSON. my wcf services use mostly GETs and return JSON. You can do POSTs with JSON content if you need it. For Android, you can do most simple HTTP stuff with either the HttpClient or HttpUrlConnection (Android recommends HttpUrlConnection). If you need to do multipart entities, i suggest the Apache HttpMime library.